# Support the repository attribute in package metadata in Octopus Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy, nuspec

OctoPack / Octo.exe currently does not support the latest nuget XSD spec, and fails to run when newer elements are used in the nuspec:

Octopus-deploy Version : Octopus 3.14.1

Repro steps:

1. Create a new nuspec file with all the defaults and inside it add a repository element inside the metadata element. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd"> 
<metadata> 
<repository type="git" url="https://github.com/user/repo&quot; /> 
</metadata> 
</package>
```

2. Run OctoPack or Octo.exe with the pack command, and the following error will be shown:

```
error OCTONUGET: The element 'metadata' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'; has invalid child element 'repository' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. List of possible elements expected: 'iconUrl, references, contentFiles, title, summary, description, dependencies, language, releaseNotes, frameworkAssemblies, developmentDependency, packageTypes, licenseUrl, serviceable, tags, copyright' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd'. This validation error occurred in a 'repository' element.
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: When deploying a package through octopus I was facing an issue regarding nuget package as repository element is not supported in the version of octopus I am using.